# Raise exception if values aren't set on initialisation

Tags: c#

I have designed a lot of models like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public bool SecondHand { get; set; }
}
```

This kind of "incomplete" initialisation doesn't raise any compiler exceptions:

```
new Book
{
    Title = "Welcome to the The"
}
```

But I would like it to error at compile time, because a few non-nullable fields (`int` not `int?`) are not initialised.

How can I design models so that, upon instantiation, failing to initialise their non-nullable fields throws errors at compile time?

(And prevents compilation)

---

I like using the `new Book { ... }` instantiation syntax, instead of a constructor `new Book(...)`, because I can see all the field names laid out before me, very visibly.

If possible, I would like a solution that can preserve this.

Comment: they are auto initialized with their default values. like for int its 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require that the mandatory properties are set via a constructor. For example, if `PageCount` is mandatory:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(int pageCount)
    {
      this.PageCount = pageCount;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; }
    public bool SecondHand { get; set; }
}
```

Now you won't be able to instanciate an instance of `Book` without correctly initializing it.

Now you can say:

```
new Book(10)
{
  Title = "Welcome to the The"
}
```

If you want to be more explicit then you can use named parameters:

```
new Book(pageCount : 10)
{
  Title = "Welcome to the The"
}
```

In the example above, if you want to make `PageCount` modifiable after it has been initialized in the constructor then you can give it a public setter, but still require initialization via the constructor.

Comment: i think there is no need of `private` `set`

Comment: @InBetween - What is valid will depend on the use case.

Comment: But why a private setter? Simply disallowing the default constructor is enough... your private setter is not adding any value at all.

Comment: How can I do it without being forced to change my initialisation syntax? I don't want to have to change all `new Book { ... }` to `new Book(...)`, because I like having all the field names laid out clearly visible when it's instantiated.

Comment: @minseong you cant. Its either one option or the other. If you allow a default constructor, you are allowing your type to behave this way... if that is not what you want, the only alternative the language provides is through custom constructors.

Comment: @minseong - You can't. If you want to force certain properties to be set then you need to do it via the initializer.

Comment: @minseong - I've updates the answer to show how using named parameters might improve readability.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to avoid this is disallowing the syntax altogher. This is feasable by simply avoiding the default constructor:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(string title, int PageCount, bool secondHand) { ... }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public bool SecondHand { get; set; }
}
```